# For each day, get query row count for that day

Tags: postgresql

Consider a PostgreSQL table (pseudo-sql):

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  time TIMESTAMPTZ,
  success BOOLEAN,
  foreign_id FOREIGN KEY,
  …
);
```

[Sample prepared dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8f5f3ad39dfd8df808339781ec2544c7)

I can run a query to get the last event for each `foreign_id` to essentially get its current status. I can therefore see that at `NOW()` there are N `foreign_id`s in the `success` state. AFAIK this involves applying a `ROW_NUMBER()` over a window grouped by `foreign_id` then filtering for `row_number = 1`, or `SELECT DISTINCT ON (foreign_id) … ORDER BY time DESC`.

What I would like is the total count of `foreign_id`s in `"success"` state for each day in the past x days.

So for the count for 3 days ago, I would only consider `events` rows with a `time` up until 3 days ago, then take the latest/final row for each `foreign_id` to get its current status 3 days ago, then of all of those rows, count how many were in `success` state.

The key thing is that this count would go up *and* down over time, for example maybe 3 days ago there were 10 `foreign_id`s in `success` state but right now there are only 4. I would like to capture this.

So ideally I get back something that looks like:

```
SELECT "day", foreign_ids_in_success_state …
```

With data that looks something like this:

```
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Day | Count of Events with 'successful' status up until that day |
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1   |                             10                             |
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2   |                              5                             |
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 3   |                              7                             |
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 4   |                              2                             |
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So what I want is:

1. for each day irrespective of whether there are events on that day or not
2. get the latest event for each foreign_id **up until that day**, e.g. for the day 3 days ago, pretend `NOW()` is 3 days ago, then get what *would be* the latest event for each foreign_id 3 days ago, i.e. disregard any rows newer than 3 days ago
3. of all of those events, count how many were `success IS TRUE`

I believe some `CROSS JOIN`s with `generate_series()` may be required for this kind of thing but I'm having trouble reasoning about it.

If this kind of thing has a name or relevant terms, I would appreciate learning it/them since I feel like it might not be a unique/rare situation.

Comment: @BrendanMcCaffrey Hello! I have [updated the fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ce099d6c54e4cd2f702bd67be0ac3f55). Please let me know if that helps and if you would like any further changes or have any other questions/comments!

Comment: I see what you mean. I haven't gotten it to work in fiddle. The fiddle demonstrates the schema, the kind of data, and how I can obtain the results for the current point in time i.e. `NOW()`, but I would like to compute this for each day going back say e.g. 30 days. I left a comment referring to this in the final block. I will edit my post with a mockup of the expected output but I'm not sure how helpful it'd be. Please let me know what you think though and I will do my best.

Comment: Also, apologies but I have made a final tweak to the final panel in the fiddle. I've updated the links in the comment and the post, but also [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ce099d6c54e4cd2f702bd67be0ac3f55). I basically moved the `WHERE success IS TRUE` out of the CTE because I think that may have been incorrect.

Comment: I have added a sample table output.

Comment: I agree. I was trying to find a way to fix that data in place. I'll just copy paste values for now. May take me a few minutes.

Comment: I have fixed the data in place. Updated the fiddle link in the post, it is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8f5f3ad39dfd8df808339781ec2544c7).

Answer (score 1):

Would this be what you're looking for?

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', ts) AS "day", COUNT(*)
FROM events
WHERE success IS TRUE
GROUP BY date_trunc('day', ts)
ORDER BY Day DESC
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e09367af5bb4a1e4fef623df0cc5b35c)

Comment: Thank you, upvoted, but I see now where the confusion lies. I believe this will give me the count of "successful" events on each day. What I want is: 1) for each day irrespective of whether there are events on that day or not, 2) get the latest event for each foreign_id 3) of all of those events, count how many were `success IS TRUE`. I will add this to my post. Please tell me if that remains unclear.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid this wasn't exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: I should clarify number 2) "get the latest event for each foreign_id **up until that day**". i.e., if it were that day right now, get the latest state for each foreign_id as if we didn't see any events after that day

Comment: I think the first sentence is correct. So this is a table of point-in-time statuses for each foreign key right. So maybe yesterday foreign_key 2 has a row for `success = false` because it failed, but then today it ran again and it succeeded so there's a row today that says `success = true`. Knowing this, for each foreng_key we can obtain what its "last known" status was. Then we can count how many are last-known to be successful. The trick is that I want to know this "last known" status for each day going back 30 days.

Comment: For example, if we went back in time to 3 days ago (i.e. disregard rows newer than 3 days ago), what would the "last known" successful count have been. I want this count for each day going back 30 days ago.